# Spring mvc .ajax success with if clause

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

I have a script with should update a div based on the value of a boolean variable i get from a Spring Controller, but i cannot get it to be used.

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{idPiano}")
    public String showFlooorMap(ModelMap model, @PathVariable int idPiano){
        Piano piano = pianoService.findById(idPiano);
        String filename = piano.getFileName();
        boolean daAggiornare = updateMap.isToUpdate();
        model.addAttribute("idPiano", idPiano);
        model.addAttribute("filename", filename);
        model.addAttribute("daAggiornare", daAggiornare); //this is the variable to check


        return "floors/map";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/ajax/{idPiano}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String loadMap(@PathVariable int idPiano){
        Piano piano = pianoService.findById(idPiano);
        boolean daAggiornare = updateMap.isToUpdate();
        String filename = piano.getFileName();
        String result ="da aggiornare: "+daAggiornare+"<br/>"
                + "<img src=\"/uploads/"+filename+"\" class=\"center-block\"/>";


            return result;
    }
```

`daAggiornare` is the variable I pass to the JSP page to check if i need to update or not the div.

In my map.jsp I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateMap() {
        var aggiorna = ${daAggiornare};
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax/${idPiano}',
            success : function(data) {
                if(aggiorna){
                $('#result').html(data);
                } 
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(updateMap, 5000);
</script>
```

I cannot see the image... But if I put off the if condition, my image is shown and refreshed every 5 seconds...